Materials inside solar cells
For my thesis as a physics student, I am doing an LCA on PV modules. Does anyone know the percentage and purity of Si inside a solar cell? (e.g. is it 100% Si or 95% Si and 5% some other material)

Avoid using too many abbreviations (it will make googling less effective). Note: I think there are already many LCA studies, and it depends on technology: you should be able to find much information online. I think it is a wafer (chip), so there are various other materials and some doping.

Also please use the correct capitalization for abbreviations, acronyms & element names. It makes it easier for people to read.

Very pure.
In monocrystalline solar cells (the most common type today), the silicon is nearly of the same purity as the silicon used to make integrated circuits. That's electronic grade silicon.
That's 6 to 9 nines, or from 99.9999% to 99.9999999% purity. For solar cells, the lower end of that range, 99.9999% if good enough, whereas modern integrated circuits tend to use purity closer to 99.9999999%.
Metallurgical grade silicon, 99% pure, forms the start of the process. It is converted to volatile gases such as silane, then distilled to make 99.9999% to 99.9999999% purity and converted back from the volatile gases to pure silicon, and then melted, and the Czochralski method is used to grow a single crystal out of the melt by using a seed crystal. The single crystal is cut to wafers, and the wafers form the basis of the solar cells.
Solar cells need a P-N junction. That is generally made by having for example a P-type wafer (doped with boron for example) and then diffusion makes the N-type layer on the top (doped with phosphorus for example). The doping levels are generally 10^15 atoms per cm^3 or measured in tens of parts per billion. So even after doping, the purity is still very great and the doping doesn't affect the purity much. However, the types of dopants (phosphorus and boron) are the types of impurities that aren't generally found in the 99.9999% purity silicon that was used to make the wafers.

thank you for taking time to answer my question that was very helpfull
